# Why doesn't this code deadlock?

Tags: c#, locking, thread-safety, deadlock

I expect the following code to deadlock when Clear tries to lock on the same object that Build has already locked:

```
void Main()
{
    (new SiteMap()).Build();
}

class SiteMap
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public void Build()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Build");
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clear");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

Clear

Build

**Edit 1**

Thank you all for your answers.

If I add a call to Build inside the lock of Clear (keeping the rest of the code the same):

```
public void Clear()
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        Build();

        Console.WriteLine("Clear");
    }
}
```

A deadlock does occur (or at least that's what I think, LINQ Pad crashes).

According to your answers, this shouldn't happen, because it's still the same thread.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx, under "Nested Locking."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C#, a thread holding a lock can enter the same lock without blocking.

The `lock` statement, as well as the [Monitor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) on which it is built, is [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_%28subroutine%29) in .NET.

---

Edit in response to your edit:

When you add the call to `Build` inside clear, the code doesn't deadlock - it is calling itself recursively.  It's not *blocking*, but rather running forever (until, eventually, you hit a [StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx)), because `Build` calls `Clear` which calls `Build` again which calls `Clear`, etc....

Comment: Regarding my edit, I really don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks for both answers!

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) says:

> If another thread attempts to enter a locked code, it will wait (block) until the object is released.

The key word is "another". A thread does not block itself, just other threads. If another thread had owned the lock, then `lock` would block.

This saves a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 4):

I will not because clear is called within the same thread which already applied the lock.